# global name 'Prefetch' is not defined

Tags: django

I am using django 1.7.1 and trying to use the Prefetch object as per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related)
But I get a name error `global name 'Prefetch' is not defined`.
My query looks like this:

```
  prefetch = Observation.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('flowers__observations'))
```

What am I missing here? I cannot find any examples anywhere using the Prefetch object.

I want to use Prefetch because it allows you to pass it a custom queryset. I need to filter the results from prefetch_related, and the Prefetch objects seems like the best way to do it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to [import `Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch)
Add this along with your list of imports:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
```